# Make a file a Stationery pad via command line

Tags: finder, applescript, command-line

Is there a way to set make a file into a Stationery pad from the command line?

You can do it by clicking "Get info" on a file and checking the box, but I would like to do it without clicking.

[image: Get Info dialog]

An AppleScript solution would be useful also, but GUI scripting is off limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SetFile utility is provided with Xcode, which Apple distributes at no cost. Once you have installed Xcode, you can issue the command

```
SetFile -a T /path/to/foo.bar
```

Answer (score 2):

After failing to find a non-AppleScript way to do this, I bit the bullet.

The AppleScript:

```
 tell application "Finder" to set stationery of ¬
   (POSIX file "/path/to/foo.bar" as alias) to true
```

You can run this from the command line using

```
osascript -e command
```