# How to close Preview with keyboard shortcuts only and not auto-save the file?

Tags: macos, preview, monterey

I want to be able to open an image, sketch some stuff, then close Preview in one or two keyboard shortcuts, without the image file being changed.

At the moment, if I open a file, sketch some stuff, then close Preview (cmd-w or cmd-q), Preview saves the file automatically, and then quits.

How can I set this to not automatically apply and save changes to my original file?

Answer (score 2):

Go to *System Settings > Desktop & Dock* and disable **Ask to keep changes when closing documents**.

Unfortunately, this disables the warning that appears when you close an app (with an unsaved document open) in ***all*** built-in app (i.e. Pages, Keynote, etc.).

[image: Screenshot taken on macOS Ventura of System Settings while setting the above-described option (Ask to keep changes when closing documents)]

Comment: It sounds like you might have understood the opposite of what my question is asking? At the moment, I am not being asked whether to keep changes or not. I found the same option in Monterey, it's in System Preferences > General. But for some reason I can't select "Revert Changes" with cmd-backspace like I used to be able to. Do you know how to discard the changes by default on file close, or easily manually discard the changes?

Comment: @theonlygusti "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" also contains auto-save. With this setting enabled, the saving will be manual and will *not* occur if you quit the document (since it would be automatic saving - *no question such as "Do you want to save the changes?"*). Also, if you want to quit Preview with keyboard shortcuts only, you can use Command+Option+Esc.

Comment: @theonlygusti Command+Option+Esc with "Ask to keep changes..." disabled works for me. Does it for you?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Stationary Pad](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-document-templates-on-mac-mchlp1341/mac) setting to open a copy of the item (document, image, etc.).  It will force a “Save As…” prompt and not touch your original.

To access “Stationary Pad” use the *Get Info* feature by selecting the file and pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> or right clicking and selecting the *Get Info* menu option.

[image]

You can create an Automator service which can reside on your desktop or as a Service (accessed by right clicking) to automate this task for you.

See [Make a file a Stationery pad via command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/39490/119271) for an AppleScript that accomplishes this (literally a one line script).  Simply save that as an Automator service. You can even add in a step to open it in Preview after Stationary Pad is set.

Making it a service like this allows you to retain the default actions of Preview (or other native macOS apps) while giving you a quick way to ensure you’re not modifying the original.